# (C basics) LinkedList: local elements get deleted after insert method

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to write a LinkedList in C,
I defined the construct in the file as `struct element { int value; struct element * next; };`
I also defined a head element.
Both of these are not local, they are variables that persist throughout runtime.
When I try to insert elements into the LinkedList using `int`-values from outside, I need to wrap an `element` around this `int`. I do this by creating a local variable `struct element e = { value; 0 };`. I make it the head if head is null, or else I append it using a for-loop.

The problem I figured is that the local variable `e` of type `struct element` is deleted upon terminating that function. So if I have my head point to `e`, it will continue pointing to an unallocated point of memory since the local variable `e` does not persist beyond the function call.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `struct element e = { value; 0 };` allocates the element on the stack. Stacks are automatically deallocated (deleted) when the function scope terminates. Addressing stack memory of an active scope is perfectly valid, but that of a scope that has terminated is undefined behavior.

You need to allocate it on the heap via `malloc(sizeof(struct element));` to make it persist through function scopes.

```
struct element *e = calloc(1, sizeof(struct element));
e->value = value;

return e;
```

Note: `calloc` allocates zeroed out memory, `malloc` allocates memory with undefined content.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped.
How do I disallocate memory e.g. when I delete an element?

Comment: `free(e);` deallocates heap memory which was previously allocated using `malloc` or `calloc` or a memory object which was modified using `realloc`. Keep in mind that you cannot deallocate part of memory which was retrieved using those calls. Also deallocating any pointer which was retrieved in another way or which has previously already been deallocated will at best cause a SIGSEGV and at worst undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamically allocated item of list of type **struct element**.

```
p_element = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
// check if successfully allocated
// initialize element fields: p_element->value = ...
p_element->next = NULL; // always terminator
if (!gp_head_element)
    // initialize head
    gp_head_element = p_element;
else {
    //  search for the end of list and append
}
```